# Hold torque during pause to change filament

Tags: change-filament

How can I achieve keeping the motors active during pause to avoid moving their position during filament changes?  I have changed the filament during some prints to change the color or to change the a newer spool, but sometimes the X axis is moved during the change. I'm now using some cloth clips to prevent moving during this change.

To pause the 3D printer I'm using the LCD menu ->pause, then I go to Move axis X, then I move close to 0. This change is manually and random since I don't know when the old filament reel is going to finish. The printer use Marlin as firmware with Ramps 1.4

Comment: Please describe how you activate the pause (e.g. menu button, or from g-code). Motors should keep their power during pauses. Also post the firmware you are using.

Comment: In addition, please provide your printer make&model, and firmware if known.

Comment: Please see https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363/wouldnt-the-filament-tag-alone-suffice-for-this-question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is `ADVANCED_PAUSE_FEATURE` enabled in your printers `configuration_adv.h` file?
There is a `PAUSE_PARK_NO_STEPPER_TIMEOUT` option included in there, which prevents the steppers from timing out during a pause, and may be more robust than a G-Code command if you plan to manually pause and resume the print instead of setting it up in the slicer.

Alternatively, in the same file,

```
#define DEFAULT_STEPPER_DEACTIVE_TIME 120
#define DISABLE_INACTIVE_X true
#define DISABLE_INACTIVE_Y true
#define DISABLE_INACTIVE_Z true  // set to false if the nozzle will fall down on your printed part when print has finished.
#define DISABLE_INACTIVE_E true
```

can be found. You may want to increase the `DEFAULT_STEPPER_DEACTIVE_TIME`, or set

```
#define DISABLE_INACTIVE_X true
#define DISABLE_INACTIVE_Y true
#define DISABLE_INACTIVE_Z true  // set to false if the nozzle will fall down on your printed part when print has finished.
```

to `false` to keep X, Y and Z engaged while allowing movement of the extruder stepper only.

Comment: thanks, I will use this line #define PAUSE_PARK_NO_STEPPER_TIMEOUT // Enable for XYZ steppers to stay powered on during filament change.

Answer (score 3):

I have not tried this, but you could use the `M84 S0` command, this prevents the motors to go into an idle state.

From the [`M84` G-code wiki](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M84:_Stop_idle_hold) (firmware specific!):

> On ***Marlin***, Repetier and RepRapFirmware, M84 can also be used to
>   configure or disable the idle timeout. For example, `M84 S10` will
>   idle the stepper motors after 10 seconds of inactivity. `M84 S0` will
>   disable idle timeout; steppers will remain powered up regardless of
>   activity.

What rests is to implement this command into your G-code file to be executed during pause. Depending on the pause method you could introduce this command. I have not tried this, but you could put the command in your start G-code and test if the motors keep powered!

Furthermore, *a specific filament change command is available for specific firmware applications*. This code, [`M600`](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M600:_Filament_change_pause), can be used to change filament. From the [Marlin documentation](http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M600.html) you can read (since you are using Marlin Firmware, you could use this G-code command):

> The `M600` command initiates the filament change procedure. The basic
>   procedure will move the print head away from the print, eject the
>   filament, wait for new filament to be inserted and the user to
>   confirm, load and prime the filament, and continue with the print.
>   `M600` may be initiated automatically if a filament runout sensor is
>   installed.

Please do note that in Marlin Firmware the `M600` command is only available when the comments before `//#define ADVANCED_PAUSE_FEATURE` in the advanced configuration options file [Configuration_adv.h](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/Configuration_adv.h) are removed, hereby activating the command.